# Find and prove asymptotic upperbound for T(n)

Tags: asymptotics, recurrence-relation

[image]

How would I go about solving this?

Comment: Don't use images as main content of your post. This makes your question impossible to search and inaccessible to the visually impaired; [we don't like that](http://meta.cs.stackexchange.com/questions/752/should-we-do-anything-about-questions-that-are-just-a-scan-of-a-problem-in-their). Please transcribe text and mathematics (note that you can [use LaTeX](http://meta.cs.stackexchange.com/questions/271/add-short-reference-for-latex-commands)) and don't forget to give proper attribution to your sources!

Answer (score 1):

Can you show that $T(\,)$ is increasing? That is, can you show that $T(n)< T(m)$ for $n<m$? If you can, then $T(n/5) \le T((7n)/10)$ so
$$
T(n) \le 2T(\frac{7}{10}n) + 3n
$$
and the upper bound of this is easy to compute by, say, the [Master Theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Master_theorem).